# Added axis2 as a maven dependency in my project

Tags: maven, maven-3, apache-axis

Moving my J2EE web project to maven. I am using axis2 1.7.8 in my existing code and it has all the jars in the WEB-INF/lib which are in axis2 1.7.8. I am adding the following dependency in the my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
  <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.8</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I am using intelliJ Idea. I ran Maven Install and then ran the package lifecycles . I excepted all the jars which are part of axis2 1.7.8 in the generated war's lib directory. But there is no war in the generated war.

I am new to maven. what am I doing wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use type `pom`, erase the `<type>` line.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the <type> but got this error. 

Failure to find org.apache.axis2:axis2:jar:1.7.8 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Comment: Oh, I see, this is a parent POM. Why do you want it as dependency?

Comment: because my project has other non axis dependecy. Sorry my knowledge of maven is rudementary